# ArangoDB: Evaluation of undefined keys in AQL filters with numeric range expressions

Tags: arangodb

I have a need to execute end-user-composed, complex AQL filter expressions against collections with highly variable document structures. These filter expressions may contain range tests that cross zero, such as "doc.x < 10", but in these cases, documents that do not have the field 'x' defined will be returned as results due to NULL being interpreted as 0 by ArangoDB. This can be avoided by writing "doc.x != NULL && doc.x < 10"; however, this results in extra complexity especially when the filter expressions are complex to begin with.

Oddly, the ==, >, >= operators do not convert NULL values - only the <, <=, and != operators. Perhaps this is a bug (using ver 3.3.2)?

This behavior will likely result in user confusion/frustration at the very least. So, before I write my own query pre-processor to work-around this, I was curious if there is a way to disable this default NULL AQL behavior (for numeric expressions)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the ArangoDB devs and it turns out this behavior is working-as-designed. The current [documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/AQL/Fundamentals/TypeValueOrder.html) is actually clear, I just hadn't looked at it in a while. The work-around is simply to add "doc.x != null" terms wherever they are needed, but for our particular use case this is a bit of a showstopper.

Comment: updated documentation link https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.8/aql/fundamentals-type-value-order.html

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

```
0 == null                 // false
```

which implies the same behavior for other comparison operators. So yeah, seems like a bug. Very weird that `>=` works but not `<=`, have you tested it with negative values as well, i.e. does `NULL >= -1` return false?

<strike>If yes, then replacing `doc.x < value` with `!(doc.x >= value)` should work.</strike>

(**Edit**: Nevermind. This doesn't distinguish between `doc.x == NULL` and `doc.x < value`.)

If not, you will have to add null checks, although i'd be surprised if you notice a significant performance bump because of that.

Comment: I just checked with negative values... sometimes it works as expected, other times it does not. I will submit a ticket.